# Running as an exe but only gets ran once

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a small programme to trim text from a line when copied to the clip board. It works perfectly. However I am going to be using this multiple times and I keep having to run the exe I created each time I want it to trim a word. 
I have tried various while loops but none to my success. I hope this is clear on what I am after? Below is the code

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
clip_text = root.clipboard_get()




data = clip_text.strip('Trim here ')
root.clipboard_append(data)
```

Comment: no it's not clear, sorry.

Comment: It works only for the new copied text. When I copy another text it doesn't work